# How do retrieve the specific value of an AWS Secrets Manager secret?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, maven, aws-secrets-manager, secret-key

I have this java code that retrieves the values from a secret:

```
public class fetchSecrets {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String secretId = "test";
        SecretsManagerClient secretsClient = SecretsManagerClient.builder()
                .region(Region.EU_WEST_1)
                .build();
        fetchPassword(secretsClient, secretId);
        secretsClient.close();
    }

    public static void fetchPassword(SecretsManagerClient secretsClient, String secretId) {
        try {
            GetSecretValueRequest valueRequest = GetSecretValueRequest.builder()
                .secretId(secretId)
                .build();
            GetSecretValueResponse valueResponse = secretsClient.getSecretValue(valueRequest);
            String secret = valueResponse.secretString();
            System.out.println(secret);
        } catch (SecretsManagerException e) {
            System.err.println(e.awsErrorDetails().errorMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this code, I get:

```
{"username":"test","password":"password123456"}
```

How do i output **only** the value of the password or the username keys?

So expected output is e.g. `password123456`

Comment: This is a json string, so just create a json object and get value with "password" key ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out I had to create a json object and pass in the string to extract its value:

```
try {
    GetSecretValueRequest request = GetSecretValueRequest.builder()
           .secretId(secretId)
           .build();

    GetSecretValueResponse valueResponse = secretsClient.getSecretValue(request);
    String secret = valueResponse.secretString();

    //defining a JSON string     
    Object obj = JSONValue.parse(secret); 
   
    //creating an object of JSONObject class
    //and casting the object into JSONObject type  
    JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;   
 
    //getting values form the JSONObject
    //and casting that values into corresponding types  
    String username = (String) jsonObject.get("username");    

    //printing the values   
    System.out.println(username); 

} catch (SecretsManagerException e) {
    System.err.println(e.awsErrorDetails().errorMessage());
    System.exit(1);
}
```

Output : `password123456`

Answer (score 4):

I suggest doing the following:
first, create a class called User like this:

```
public class User {

    private String username;
    private String  password;

    //setter
    void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    //getter
    String getUsername(){
        return this.username;
    }

    String getPassword(){
        return this.password;
    }
}
```

Then you can retrieve the password like this:

```
User user = gson.fromJson(secret , User.class);
System.out.println(user.getPassword());
```

Comment: this is ok, but i was hoping to keep everything in the same class instead of creating a new one

Comment: In my opinion, encapsulate the User into a class is more preferable because if a new field is added in the future you just have to modify the user class and add setter and getter to it, without any need to parse the JSON object one more time and get the specified field.